# I am trying to access a private member variable through reflection but getting java.lang.NoSuchFieldException

Tags: java, reflection, private-members

```
public class AccessPrivateMember {
    private String privateName;

    public AccessPrivateMember(String privateName) {
        super();
        this.privateName = privateName;
    }

    public String getPrivateName() {
        return privateName;
    }

    public void setPrivateName(String privateName) {
        this.privateName = privateName;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

        AccessPrivateMember objAccessPrivateMember = new AccessPrivateMember("Secret Name");
        /*
         * Field reflectionAPIField=
         * objAccessPrivateMember.getClass().getDeclaredField("privateName"); String
         * secretName = (String) reflectionAPIField.get(objAccessPrivateMember);
         * System.out.println("secretName="+secretName);
         */
        Field reflectionAPIField2= AccessPrivateMember.class.getClass().getDeclaredField("privateName");
        reflectionAPIField2.setAccessible(true);        
        String secretName2ndWay = (String) reflectionAPIField2.get(objAccessPrivateMember);
        System.out.println("secretName2ndWay="+secretName2ndWay);
    }

}
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: privateName
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Unknown Source)
    at io.java.interview.AccessPrivateMember.main(AccessPrivateMember.java:31)
```

1. Line Number 31 is

   ```
   Field reflectionAPIField2 = AccessPrivateMember.class.getClass().getDeclaredField("privateName");
   ```
2. The code commented is printing the correct result and it is also accessing the private instance variable by privateName. But the line 31 is giving above error.

Comment: Change line 31 to below:
    Field reflectionAPIField2= AccessPrivateMember.getClass().getDeclaredField("privateName");

Answer (score 2):

He, Welcome to Stackoverflow.

The below line is incorrect:

```
  Field reflectionAPIField2= AccessPrivateMember.class.getClass().getDeclaredField("privateName");
reflectionAPIField2.setAccessible(true);
```

Change this to

```
   Field reflectionAPIField2= AccessPrivateMember.class.getDeclaredField("privateName");
reflectionAPIField2.setAccessible(true);
```

As described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html)

> If an instance of an object is available, then the simplest way to get its Class is to invoke Object.getClass().

In your code `Field reflectionAPIField2= AccessPrivateMember.class` is not an instance, hence it does not work.

Comment: @KuldeepRana Please mark it as correct as it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your line 31 with

```
Field reflectionAPIField2 = AccessPrivateMember.class.getDeclaredField("privateName");
```